# Async Servlet - getting file greater than fileSizeThreshold

Tags: java, servlets, nio

I'm wondering about connection of **fileSizeThreshold** size from **@MultipartConfig** and getting file from request like this:

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = (ByteArrayInputStream) request.getPart("file").getInputStream();
```

Why when file is greater size then fileSizeThreshold it will get into Throwable catch inside FutureTask?

I need this for AsynchronousFileChannel, am I doing it wrong?

Sorry if there is not enough data about my problem, I will write more if it will be necessary

Comment: Since nio can't block there is no chance to receive a large amount of information since that would mean block and block and block untill all chuncks are received. Nio works by receiving one chunk each time and then wait async'ly for another chunk. Anything to do with that?

Comment: Thank you, it actually help me to realize what am I doing wrong :) Now I have to find out how to fix that :p